# "the co-founder" vs. "a co-founder"

Tags: articles

One friend of mine and I were discussing stress and I talked about my experience about running a company. I started the sharing with this

> I was **the co-founder** of a small company.

I used "the" because the company only had a founder and a co-founder though I didn't say it explicitly.

Should have I used this one?

> I was **a co-founder** of a small company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there were actually only two co-founders as you say, then what you used was fine:

> I was **the co-founder** of a small company.

If you don't want to make that explicit nor imply that there more co-founders, you can use no article:

> I was **co-founder** of a small company.

This would be in line with the "unique role" characterization Quirk *et al* make of the zero article with singular count nouns in complement position on page 276 of their *Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*:

[image: Unique role]

Answer (score 0):

I think "a co-founder" is slightly better, since 'the' implies there is only one. I'm unfamiliar with the idea of a 'founder' and one 'co-founder'; the "co-" prefix implies that the two of you founded the company and a rough equality is presumed. I suppose it doesn't have to be that way, though; we don't tend to use "assistant founder" as an idea.

I don't think it makes a lot of difference either way.

Comment: Maybe it's like sine and cosine?

Comment: No.............     ...